# dispatch_sync call into a dispatch_async call

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I get some doubts about behavior of this code :

```
dispatch_async(queue, ^{
    sleep(2);
    NSLog(@"step1");

    dispatch_sync(queue, ^{
        sleep(3);
        NSLog(@"step 2");
    });

    NSLog(@"step 3");
});
```

From these rows i expected to get as output `step1 -> step3 -> step2` but i obtain only `step1`.

If i change dispatch_sync with dispatch_async it works as expected, Does dispatch_sync into a dispatch_async call create this kind of problem ?

**Edit after answers ----------------**

This case create a deadlock:

You can check accepted answer to have explanation of this situation and check this link for documentation http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That's a deadlock.

The `dispatch_sync` call will be waiting until `queue` is available before running its block and returning but that won't be available until the `dispatch_async` has finished so it will just sit there spinning waiting to call `dispatch_sync`.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @mattjgalloway, it is a deadlock.

Apple's own documentation mentions the problem here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man3/dispatch_async.3.html (see "RECURSIVE LOCKS"). It is discussed in the context of recursive locks, but the principle is the same.