# Dealing with Blocks, completion handlers, dispatch_async vs dispatch_sync

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm executing an online fetch of data in a thread and I want to do something immediately after the block is executed.

Here's my code:

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"checking");
    [self editToolbar];
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Refreshing", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        [self fetchImonggoItemsDataIntoDocument: self.itemDatabase];
    });
    dispatch_release(fetchQ); 

    NSLog(@"done checking");
    //do something here
}
```

The thing is dispatch_async returns immediately and "done checking" prints immediately even before the block is done executing. How do I solve this?

Comment: Why don't you put whatever it is you want to do at the end of the Block? Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: Is the problem that `performBlock:` returns right away (runs asynchronously)? There's always `performBlockAndWait:`, as long as it's on a background thread.

Comment: @acecapades i think you need to debug your code and after that get what is the exact point from where your control returns !!

Comment: @acecapades try these links
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3379008/how-can-i-be-notified-when-a-dispatch-async-task-is-complete

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8668585/dispatch-sync-call-into-a-dispatch-async-call

Comment: Try dispatch_sync in place of dispatch_async

Comment: thanks @Amit I tried that, but it still didn't work. Thanks though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's an architectural issue. The tasks are something like:

1. edit toolbar
2. fetchImonggoItemsDataIntoDocument
3. do something else

If these must be done exactly in order then I don't quite understand the use of blocks or queues; just run the statements after each other and you'll be set.

Otherwise, alternative #1 would be to use `dispatch_sync` rather than `dispatch_async`. Again, I'm not quite sure what the benefit of using a queue would be but there it is.

Alternative #2 would be to use a callback from the block. Something like:

```
- (IBAction)refresh:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    NSLog(@"checking");
    [self editToolbar];
    dispatch_queue_t fetchQ = dispatch_queue_create("Refreshing", NULL);
    dispatch_async(fetchQ, ^{
        [self setupFetchedResultsController];
        [self fetchImonggoItemsDataIntoDocument: self.itemDatabase];
        [self doneChecking]; // <-- NOTE! call the callback
    });
    dispatch_release(fetchQ); 
}

// NOTE! refresh: has been split up into two methods
- (void)doneChecking:
    NSLog(@"done checking");
    //do something here
}
```

Comment: It's also possible to enqueue another block to do the callback business, again using `dispatch_async`, but there's really no reason not to do it the way you've written here. (I don't even understand why this was a question...)

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if `doneChecking` is going to operate on any UI elements that it should be done in the main thread and not in fetchQ. Use another dispatch call but just request the main queue.

Answer (score 1):

As others have already suggested, this is probably what you need.

```
NSArray *items = [iMonggoFetcher fetchImonggoData:IMONGGO_GENERIC_URL_FOR_PRODUCTS withFormat:@"json" withDateRangeArgs:args];
[document.managedObjectContext performBlock:^{
    for (NSDictionary *itemInfo in items){
        [Product productWithImonggoInfo:itemInfo inManagedObjectContext:document.managedObjectContext];
    }
    // Put here what you need :)
}];
```