# Save to docs directory with completion block?

Tags: objective-c

I have a method to save an image to the documents directory. Looks like this:

```
+(void)saveImageInDocumentsDirectory:(UIImage *)image withImageName:(NSString *)name { 
    NSArray * paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString * basePath = ([paths count] > 0) ? [paths objectAtIndex:0] : nil;
    NSData * binaryImageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    [binaryImageData writeToFile:[basePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",name]] atomically:YES];  
}
```

Is there a way to add a completion block to this, that will run when the image is saved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think that there is a completion block. According to the docs, the return value indicates

**Return Value**
*YES if the operation succeeds, otherwise NO.*

To me this means that the method would block the thread it is called from until it is done.
If your saving is taking some time, you could use Grand Central Dispatch to execute the operation in a separate thread. You could call a method to be used as completion block when your method returns. Look for `dispatch_async` and you should find a lot.

There are also tons of examples here on SO. For example:
[Dealing with Blocks, completion handlers, dispatch_async vs dispatch_sync](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510225/dealing-with-blocks-completion-handlers-dispatch-async-vs-dispatch-sync)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You could add an additional parameter to your method that represents the completion block. However, there is no point. None of the code involved here is asynchronous. When you call this `saveImageInDocumentsDirectory:withImageName:` method, the write is already complete when the method returns. So adding a support for a completion block gains you nothing.

So instead of adding support for a completion block and making a call like this:

```
[Whatever saveImageInDocumentsDirectory:someImage withImageName:@"SomeName" completion:^{
    // some completion code
}];
```

You just need to do this:

```
[Whatever saveImageInDocumentsDirectory:someImage withImageName:@"SomeName"];
// some completion code here
```

Comment: Thanks, and you're right. I'll implement a combination of both these answers - run the save on a background thread, and then pop something at the end of the method to notify the UI that the save completed.